# Поиск в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив из слов, как по нажатию кнопки отыскать в массиве нужное слово и удалить его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

(находим индекс элемента методом [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) и удаляем элемент методом [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice))

```js
let a = ["один", "два", "три"];
let i = a.indexOf("два");

a.splice(i, 1);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const array = ['один', 'два', 'три'];
const arrayFiltered = array.filter(word => word !== 'два');
console.log(arrayFiltered);
```